# How to detect and stop an animation in SVG while it is queued, but not while it is running?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

Imagine both svg's are the same in some code. I want to prevent an animation from running if I click a button before the animation starts. But if the animation is running I want it to finish the animation. I used a setTimeout() to replicate the behavior of the buttonClick in two scenario's.

How do I achieve this by using javaScript?

Maybe this approach might help in getting a solution:

- step1: detect if animation is running
- step2: cancel animation **if** it is not running
- step3: **else** use `document.getElementById("animate1").setAttribute("begin", "");` to let the animation finish.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7hc6710p/1/

**svg**

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <rect width="500" height="500" x="0" y="0">
  <animate id="animate1_1" attributeType="xml" attributeName="fill" from="black" to="red" dur="5s" begin="5s; animate1_2.end" fill="freeze"/>
  <animate id="animate1_2" attributeType="xml" attributeName="fill" from="red" to="black" dur="5s" begin="animate1_1.end" fill="freeze"/>
  </rect>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <rect width="500" height="500" x="0" y="0">
  <animate id="animate2_1" attributeType="xml" attributeName="fill" from="black" to="red" dur="5s" begin="5s; animate2_2.end" fill="freeze"/>
  <animate id="animate2_2" attributeType="xml" attributeName="fill" from="red" to="black" dur="5s" begin="animate2_1.end" fill="freeze"/>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

**javascript**

```
//imagine both svg's are the same in some code. I want to prevent an animation from running if I click a button before the animation starts. But if the animation is running I want it to finish the animation. I used a setTimeout() to replicate the behavior of the buttonClick in two scenario's.

//How do I achieve this by using javaScript?

//maybe those ideas help in getting a solution:
//step1: detect if animation is running
//step2: cancel animation if it is not running, else use:
//document.getElementById("animate1").setAttribute("begin", "");
//to let the animation finish.

//scenario 1: this animation should not run. Clicked before the animation starts
document.getElementById("animate1_1").setAttribute("begin", "");

//scenario 2: this animation should finish. Clicked while the animation is running.
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("animate2_1").setAttribute("begin", "");
}, 6000);
```

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__pauseAnimations

Comment: @Robert Longson This would work in scenario 1. But  in scenario 2 I want to complete the animation if it's already running, not pause it. Another drawback is that it would apply on a `svg`-element and not on another element, like `rect`.

Comment: You're mistaken on all points. Try the DOM calls and see how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler to control the start of the animations yourself.  Then if you don't want an animation to start, don't start it running.

If an `<animate>` element doesn't have a specific start time, it will sit there waiting until you start it by calling `beginElement()`.

So in the example below, we use `setTimeout()` to schedule both animations to start running, but then cancel the first one.

```js
// The enimations to start running
var  animStartElements = ["animate1_1", "animate2_1"];
// An object we will use as a map to stor timeout handles
var  animStartTimers = {};

// Schedule each animation to start after five seconds
animStartElements.forEach(function(elemId) {
  var animElem = document.getElementById(elemId);
  // Use a timeout to schedule the start of this animation
  var timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function() {
    // beginElement() on an <animation> element starts it running
    animElem.beginElement();
  }, 5000);
  // Record the timeout handle in the animStartTimers map
  animStartTimers[elemId] = timeoutHandle;
})

// Cancel the first animation from running (eg as a response to a click)
// Comment this line out to see it run.
clearTimeout(animStartTimers["animate1_1"]);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="200">
  <rect width="500" height="500" x="0" y="0">
  <animate id="animate1_1" attributeType="xml" attributeName="fill" from="black" to="red" dur="2s" begin="animate1_2.end" fill="freeze"/>
  <animate id="animate1_2" attributeType="xml" attributeName="fill" from="red" to="black" dur="2s" begin="animate1_1.end" fill="freeze"/>
  </rect>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="200">
  <rect width="500" height="500" x="0" y="0">
  <animate id="animate2_1" attributeType="xml" attributeName="fill" from="black" to="red" dur="2s" begin="animate2_2.end" fill="freeze"/>
  <animate id="animate2_2" attributeType="xml" attributeName="fill" from="red" to="black" dur="2s" begin="animate2_1.end" fill="freeze"/>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thx for the great answer! Starting the animation with JS is definitely going to make timing the animations a lot easier.